# DB2 transparent table aliases for routing

Tags: db2

We have a situation where multiple development teams are working concurrently across a dev/uat/prod set of environments. We don't have the resources to maintain dev and uat such that they reflect up-to-date prod data, and that has an impact on the developers.

One team want to develop on a table with a cut of data from one point in time, and another on the same table with a cut from another point in time. The central table is large and unwieldy to update.

Is there a way to maintain two versions of this table, and have the two dev teams work on their own version, whilst seemingly referring to it using its two-part schema.tablename name?

It's the common isolation problem encountered by distributed/concurrent development teams.

In other words, can I set up one team (who might connect using one username) so that when they reference CORE.TABLE, they get pointed to TEAM1.TABLE, while another team, connecting via a different user, can still reference CORE.TABLE, but be pointed to the TEAM2.TABLE version of the data?

I don't believe we can be the first group to come across a problem like this, are there any useful or established methods for transparently pointing two different code-developer groups at two versions of the same table?

Comment: You don't mention which version you are using, but you may want to have a look at TENANT

Comment: TENANT appears to not have made it into 11.5.6 (don't know about 11.5.7), so it won't help you much at the moment. But you may want to keep an eye open for when it is GA, from your description it sounds like it may fit your needs.

Comment: in my experience the practice varies with industry-sector and the resources available, (i.e. cash for storage, cpu, ram, manpower, licenses).  Some regulated industries have more restrictions on where data can be copied. With competent automation skills, and depersonalisation tooling, having separated environments can be best approach, as multi-tenanting causes too many headaches operationally, especially in multi-version or mixed environments (on prem, cloud, containers etc) or complex stacks.